# Remove from stack fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, fragment

In my Android application I have 3 fragments(MainFragment, FavoriteFragment, UserFragment) and bottomnavigationview.

If I move from `Frag1-> Frag2-> Frag3` and when I press the back, return to `Fragm2`, but i want don't save fragment trace and close appication

```
private fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
       val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
       transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment)
       transaction.addToBackStack(null)
       transaction.commit()
   }
```

Comment: You committed a FragmentTransaction with `addToBackStack`. This means that the transaction will be remembered after it is committed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your issue, you want the back press to take you one fragment back instead of exiting the app, right?

If that's the case then you need to either implement your custom logic to 'replace' the fragment `onBackPressed()`

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
   // checking which is the current fragment and loading the proper one
   when(supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frameLayout)){
      is Fragment3 -> loadFragment(Fragment2.newInstance())
      is Fragment2 -> loadFragment(Fragment1.newInstance())
      else -> super.onBackPressed()
   }
}
```

or you can `add()` your fragment instead.

```
private fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
       val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
       transaction.add(R.id.frameLayout, fragment)
       transaction.addToBackStack(null)
       transaction.commit()
}
```

Because you are replacing the fragment when you load them, it means that the backstack only has one instance of it so when back pressed is called it will pop the only instance and close the application.